# Samhain: Consuming too much CPU and memory

Tags: centos

I have samhain installed on centos6. Recently I realized that its constantly consuming too much of CPU and memory. Its almost eating up 2 CPU cores and 183m of memory. I don't find the reason. I am not sure what is keeping it so much busy.

I tried googling it, but could not find much information. Also if I tail /var/log/messages I see

```
Nov  1 14:20:17 prod-db Samhain[1974]: MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:20:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
Nov  1 14:21:17 prod-db Samhain[1974]: MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:21:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
Nov  1 14:22:17 prod-db Samhain[1974]: MARK   :  [2012-11-01T14:22:17-0400] msg=<---- TIMESTAMP ---->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I think it was signing issue that lead to such a performance hit. Not sure weather newer versions have some means to inform end users.

What I suspect is the samhain binary and the samhainrc/samhain_file were not signed properly or with the same key and that made samhain go crazy eating whole CPU.

Other than this there is no other reason why in one installation (some other guy did) it works and and new installation (which I did) does not.